# Pip wont update

Tags: terminal, upgrade, unix, python, package-management

Hi I am trying to update pip and receiving this error:

```
egts-iMac-3:~ egt$ pip install -U pip
 You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
 You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' 
  command.
Collecting pip
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from 
   versions: )
 No matching distribution found for pip
```

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: What does `type pip` return?

Comment: @user136952 its python 2.7.10... .@nohillside 'pip is hashed (/usr/local/bin/pip)'

Comment: Are you getting a message to upgrade pip when you attempt an install of a python package? This can happen if the package you are attempting to install with pip is out of the domain of your current (called) python interpreter.

Comment: Have you tried running the command under sudo?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out I had to update xcode, and it updated pip to 10.0.1.